# Integral $\int \frac1{\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q)}}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am working on this:

$$\int \dfrac 1 {\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q)} } \ \mathrm d x$$

valid where $(a x + b)(p x + q) > 0$.

I am specifically interested in the case where $\dfrac {b p - a q} p < 0$.

I do this:

Let $u = \sqrt {a x + b}$

$\leadsto x = \dfrac {u^2 - b} a$

$\leadsto \sqrt {p x + q} = \sqrt {p \left({\dfrac {u^2 - b} a}\right) + q}$

$= \sqrt {\dfrac {p \left({u^2 - b}\right) + a q} a}$

$= \sqrt {\dfrac {p u^2 - b p + a q} a}$

$= \sqrt {\dfrac p a} \sqrt {u^2 - \left({\dfrac {b p - a q} p}\right) }$

Then by a standard result:

$\displaystyle \int \frac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q) } } = \int \frac {2 u \mathrm d u} {a \sqrt {\frac p a} \sqrt {u^2 - \left({\frac {b p - a q} p}\right) } u}$

$= \dfrac 2 {\sqrt {a p} } \int \dfrac {\mathrm d u} {\sqrt {u^2 - \left({\dfrac {b p - a q} p}\right) } }$

Now let $\dfrac {b p - a q} p < 0$.

Let $c^2 = -\dfrac {b p - a q} p$.

This gives us:

$\displaystyle \int \dfrac 1 {\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q)} } \ \mathrm d x = \frac 2 {\sqrt {a p} } \int \frac {\mathrm d u} {\sqrt {u^2 + c^2} }$

$= \dfrac 2 {\sqrt {a p} } \sinh^{-1} {\dfrac u c} + C$ (standard result)

$= \dfrac 2 {\sqrt {a p} } \sinh^{-1} \dfrac {\sqrt {a x + b} } {\sqrt {\dfrac {a q - b p} p} } + C$

(because $\dfrac {b p - a q} p = -\dfrac {a q - b p} p$)

$= \dfrac 2 {\sqrt {a p} } \sinh^{-1} \sqrt {\dfrac {p (a x + b) } {a q - b p} } + C$

But when I look in the book (in this case Murray Spiegel's "Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables" (Schaum, 1968), I see this as result $14.120$:

$$\dfrac 2 {\sqrt {-a p} } \arctan \sqrt {\dfrac {-p (a x + b) } {a (p x + q)} } $$

EDIT 4-Jun-2023: Corrected denominator of argument of arctangent to $a (p x + q)$ from $a q - b p$.

Can't see where I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: if $\frac {b p - a q}{ p} < 0$ then $\sqrt {\frac {b p - a q} {p}}$ is wrong. Should be $\sqrt {\frac {aq-bp} {p}} $ and your final result should be $$ \frac 2 {\sqrt {a p} } \sinh^{-1} \sqrt {\frac {p (a x + b) } {aq-bp} } + C$$ which is exactly the result given by *Mathematica*

Comment: Fixed that. But where does arctan come into it?

Comment: Don't know. Derivative doesn't give back the original function $$\frac{a p}{\sqrt{-a p} (a q-b p) \sqrt{\frac{p (a x+b)}{a q-b p}} \left(\frac{p (a x+b)}{a q-b p}+1\right)}$$

Comment: Of course any $\sinh^{-1}$ can be converted to an $\sin^{-1}$ where you put an $i$ in there (here, a minus sign inside the square root).  And any $\sin^{-1}$ can be converted to an $\tan^{-1}$.  So, just from the form of your answer and Spiegel's answer, we cannot tell whether or not the two answers agree.

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry, but I don't understand how "any $\sin^{-1}$ can be converted to a $\tan^{-1}$". How is this done, in the context where we retain consistency between two forms? I can't get my head round the "of course", and on the back of that, the "cannot tell" in your final sentence is dismaying and daunting. Is there any chance you can expand on this as a full answer? I feel there may be a deeper understanding here which would be educational to explore further.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the derived solution
$$I=\int \dfrac 1 {\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q)} } d x
= \frac 2 {\sqrt {a p} } \sinh^{-1} \sqrt {\dfrac {p (a x + b) } {a q - b p} } 
$$
assumes $ap>0$, which is in contrast to $-ap>0$ assumed by the book solution

$$I= \dfrac 2 {\sqrt {-a p} } \tan^{-1} \sqrt {\dfrac {-p (a x + b) } {a (p x + q)} } $$
Thus, the two expressions are irreconcilable. If, instead, the book assumption $-ap>0$ is adopted, proceed with the derivation as follows

$$I= \int \frac {2 } {a\sqrt {{-\frac p a} \left({\frac {b p - a q} p}-u^2\right) }}du 
=\frac{2\ \text{sgn}(a)}{\sqrt{-ap}}\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt {a x + b}}{\sqrt{\frac {b p - a q} p}}$$
Note that the condition $\frac {b p - a q} p>0 $ has to be enforced under $-ap>0$ in order for the integral to exist.

Comment: I will go away and evaluate this approach, and get back to you in due course. My personal available time is limited right now, and this will likely take some time to do, so please accept my apologies if this is not immediate.

Comment: I have managed to get the given $\arctan$ solution by using the substitution $u = \sqrt {\dfrac {-p (ax + b)} {a (px + q)}}$. The algebra is fiddly but you get the required answer. The puzzle is to work out how to intuit that substitution without knowing it in advance.

Comment: @PrimeMover - you could get the $\arctan$ result from the Euler substitution of 3rd-kind naturally.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for that. That's a technique I have never seen before. Googling it I come to the relevant page in Wikipedia. That will need to be studied too.

Comment: I have worked through the process and have reached $\int \frac {\mathrm d x} {\sqrt {(a x + b) (p x + q) } } = -2 a \arctan \left ({\sqrt {-\dfrac a p} \dfrac {\sqrt {p x + q} } {\sqrt {a x + b} } }\right) + C$ so something wrong with my work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Amplified comment: "Convert an $\arcsin$ to an $\arctan$."
I learned this long ago because certain computer languages had only $\arctan$ as built-in function, and you had to use formulas if you wanted $\arcsin, \arccos$, etc.   (`BASIC` had `ATN` arctangent, but none of the other "arc" trig functions)

So here it is:

$$
\arcsin t = 2 \arctan\left(\frac{t}{1+\sqrt{1-t^2}}\right)
$$

Here are the graphs.

[image: G1]  [image]

Identical

Comment: So how does this relate to the question in question? In what way does this transformation resolve the issue about the difference between what I evaluated and what Spiegel done? This went so far over my head I didn't hear it whistle.

Comment: Okay so I finally flogged through this, but I wonder whether we can't use the simpler form $\arcsin t = \arctan \left({\dfrac t {\sqrt {1 - t^2} } }\right)$. But in any case, neither approach was particularly fruitful, leading to some difficult algebra which I could not reconcile.